# Android studio Error: Cause: invalid type code: 2A

Tags: android, android-studio-3.4

I am compiling my existing project after 1 year and It is giving the error **"Cause: invalid type code: 2A"**

I have followed the below link but no success,
[How can i fix this error in Android Studio,Cause: invalid type code: 00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52570334/how-can-i-fix-this-error-in-android-studio-cause-invalid-type-code-00)